# How to select a inserted block on editor.js?

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I am using Editor.js and i do not know how to select a block after inserting it or in general do selecting programmatically.

This is how i insert a new block:

```
this.myEditor.blocks.insert('paragraph', {text: newBlock.text)}, null, this.myEditor.blocks.getBlocksCount());
```

This works fine but how do i select now this block so in frontend, the block is marked?